# How to count characters across strings in a pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sequencing

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
prod_sec     
A    
AA    
AAAAAAAAAAB    
AAAABCCCAA    
AACC   
ABCCCBAC

df = pd.DataFrame({'prod_sec': ['A','AA','AAAAAAAAAAB','AAAABCCCAA','AACC','ABCCCBAC']})
```

Each string is a sequence made up of letters (A to C in this example).
I would like to create a list for each letter that counts the occurrences in each position down the entire pandas column.
For example in the first string A is only in the first position/index and it's not in the other locations. 
In the second string the A in the first two positions and it's not in the other locations
In the third string the A has all the positions until the last one.  Etc... 
I want a total count, for the column, by position. 
Here is an example for A:

```
A            ->     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]    
AA                  [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
AAAAAAAAAAB   ->    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0] 
AAAABCCCAA          [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
AACC                [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
ABCCCBAC    ->      [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

so for A, I would want an output similar to the following... A  [6,4,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,0]
In the end, I'm trying to get a matrix with a row for each character.

> ```
>                     [6,4,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,0]
>                     [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
>                     [0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,0]
> ```

Comment: Could you please clarify? I didn't understand from your example what you are trying to achieve

Comment: what is your expected output. it's not clear what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. You can adjust the result, depending on your exact needs (numpy array, data frame, dictionary, etc). Tell me if you need more help with that.

```
max_length=max([len(i) for i in df.prod_sec])

d={'A':[0]*max_length, 'B':[0]*max_length, 'C':[0]*max_length}

for i in df.prod_sec:
    for k in range(len(i)):
        d[i[k]][k]+=1

result=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

Comment: You are counting the characters for each cell.  I would like to have a count by position down the entire Pandas column.  I have clarified my question above.

Comment: Ok, i have updated my answer. Tell me if you need more help with the result.

Comment: Incredible. How would this be generalized instead of hardcoding the A-C? I can get all of the possibilities by `string = ''.join(set(df['prod_sec'].dropna().to_string(index = False))).strip()` but I'm not sure how to generate the dictionary.

Comment: You can do something like this:


```for i in df['prod_sec']:
    for k in i:
        d[k]=[0]*max_length```